# CFX SOAP call getting SSL error readHandshakeRecord

Tags: ssl, soap, cxf

I am using SOAP call using cxf, and getting ssl readHandshakeRecord exception

```
 unwinding now org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.  at
```

reason:

```
      java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLException invoking https://myservice/Services: readHandshakeRecord  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)  at
```

.......

I also try to skip ssl validation with trust all certs

```
static {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
        } };
        SSLContext sc = null;
        try {
            sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception ssl ",e);
        }
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new  HostnameVerifier()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
            {
                return true;
            }
        };
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    }
```

---

but still getting error

I also tries with TLSClientParameters

```
   JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceClass(Hello.class);
    factory.setAddress(address);
    Hello portType = (Hello) factory.create();
    try {
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new  HostnameVerifier()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
            {
                return true;
            }
        };
        HTTPConduit httpCon = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(portType).getConduit();
        TLSClientParameters parameters = new TLSClientParameters();
        parameters.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        parameters.setDisableCNCheck(true);
        parameters.setHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
        parameters.setTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            }
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            }
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        }});
        httpCon.setTlsClientParameters(parameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.ptintln( e);
    }
```

but still getting same error

Need your valuable help
thank you in advance!

Comment: hi, this is Prabhat from Uttarakhand

Comment: hi @PrabhatGaur